# How to Correctly Extend An Enum

Tags: bixby

I am trying to extend the `geo.StreetSuffix` enum to include some more possible values. It currently doesn't have a value for `Greene` which is a valid street suffix. This is what my concept looks like:

```
enum (StreetSuffix) {
  description (Street Suffix)
  extends(geo.StreetSuffix)
  symbol (Greene)
}
```

This is a training sample:

```
[g:Evaluate:prompt] (19)[v:geo.StreetNumber] (Fake Hills)[v:geo.StreetName] (Lane)[v:StreetSuffix:Lane]
```

When I do this though the training files give me the following error:
`Confusion Points: Match(es) on : "Lane".` and the language recognition no longer works for that value. Am I doing something wrong here, is there a bug, or is this not how Enum inheritance is supposed to work?

I am happy to write my own enum which would be a copy of `geo.StreetSuffix` but it seems like a waste if I could just extend it and add some of my own values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'd have to copy everything from the old vocab file (which you don't have access to).

> *Note*
>
> If you extend a type into another capsule, a new vocabulary file must still be created. Vocabulary is never inherited, even if you use extends or add role-of to a model.

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.vocabulary#adding-vocabulary

That being said, you can file a ticket with support to add `Greene` and any other missing values you might come across...